# InApp Purchases: Why do you have to fetch a list of products before selling them?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

ios InApp purchases: Why do you have to fetch a list of products before selling them?
Following this list: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Why do we even need to fetch the list of products before selling them?  Why not just sell the hardcoded id's we create for the app?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to sell a product without stating the price.

Comment: But you know the price when you insert the product into iTunes connect.  Why not just hardcode it into the code?  Also I seem to be able to make purchases with just the "id" which is the input into fetching the product info.

Comment: You don't know the price. You only know the tier. The price varies over region and even changes occasionally (the Australian tier-one price recently dropped from $1.19 to $0.99). You are right about being able to pay with just an ID, though; I didn't realise there was an alternate way to initialise SKPayment.